# Delete Info From Two Separate MySQL Tables Individually?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making this podcast-sharing like site where users can upload audio pod-casts and if they log into the admin page can edit each title and each URL, and delete any podcast. Here's my code, I will explain my error afterwards:

```
    <li><form action="admin.php" method="POST"><input type="submit" name="1" value = "Insects and Plants" /><input type="submit" name="2" value = "Dr. Seuss" /></forM>
    <li><p><?php
    function disp($titid,$titol,$aid){

            if($_GET['del']){
            $delete_id=$_GET['del'];
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `$titid` WHERE `$titid`.`inid` = $delete_id");
            header("location: admin.php");

            }
    echo "<a name='$aid'><h3>" . $titol . "</h3></a>";
    $result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `'.$titid.'` ORDER BY inid ASC');
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            $title = $row['title'];

            $url=$row['url'];
            $id = $row['inid'];
            echo '<div class="inneredit">';
            echo $title . '</br>';
            echo $url . '</br>'.$id.'</br>';

                    echo "<form action='admin.php' method='POST'><input type='text' name='nameedit".$id."' /><input type='submit' name='nameit$id' value='Edit Name' /></form>";
            echo "<form action='admin.php' method='POST'><input type='text' name='urledit".$id."' /><input type='submit' name='redit$id' value='Edit URL' /></form>";
            echo "<input type='button' id='delete' value='Delete Podcast' onclick='return Deleteqry($id)' />";
            echo "</div>";
            if(isset($_POST['urledit'.$id]));
                    if(isset($_POST['redit'.$id]))
                    {
                        $newd = $_POST['urledit'.$id];

                        mysql_query("UPDATE `$titid` SET url = '$newd' WHERE $titid.inid = $id ");
                        header("location: admin.php");
                    }
                                    if(isset($_POST['nameit'.$id]))
                    {
                        $newd = $_POST['nameedit'.$id];

                        mysql_query("UPDATE `$titid` SET title = '$newd' WHERE $titid.inid = $id ");
                        header("location: admin.php");
                    }
            }

            }
            if(isset($_POST['2'])){
            disp("DrSeuss","Dr. Seuss","Seussa");

            } else {
            disp("insects","Insects and Plants","Insectsa");
    }
            ?>
    <script>
            function Deleteqry(id)
            { 
              if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this audio file?")==true)
                       window.location="admin.php?del="+id;
                return false;
            }

    </script>



            ?>
```

So now when I click delete after selecting 'Dr. Seuss' it deletes the podcast (with that same id) but in the Insects table, and not the Dr. Seuss table. Can anyone help with how to help PHP differentiate between the two tables?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: Okay but for the time being how would I do this with the old mysql_* querys?

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10+ times a day

Comment: Okay the next question I post, I wont be using these old querys anymore, but for the sake of deadliens etc. is there a way to do it with mysql_*?

Comment: im not sure where $_POST['2'] is set, which is how you are determining which table to  delete from

Answer (score 1):

A look on your js function tells me that you don't have $_POST['2'] set, so your if condition on DrSeuss won't execute.